# Environment variable escaping across multiple Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What's the correct way to pass and modify environment variables through several levels of makefiles? Specifically I'm setting `LDFLAGS` in the parent makefile using the [special `$ORIGIN` RPATH value](https://enchildfone.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/a-description-of-rpath-origin-ld_library_path-and-portable-linux-binaries/), and I need to add to the variable in some of the child makefiles. The linker wants the literal string `$ORIGIN`, that's not another variable to expand.

**`Makefile`:**

```makefile
# default value for all children
export LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN'

all:
    env | grep LDFLAGS
    $(MAKE) -f child1.mk
    $(MAKE) -f child2.mk
```

**`child1.mk`:**

```makefile
# add an additional RPATH value
export LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN/../..'

all:
    env | grep LDFLAGS
```

**`child2.mk`:**

```makefile
all:
    env | grep LDFLAGS
```

#### This is what happens:

```
$ make
env | grep LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'
make -f child1.mk
make[1]: Entering directory `/build/test'
env | grep LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='RIGIN' -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/../..'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/build/test'
make -f child2.mk
make[1]: Entering directory `/build/test'
env | grep LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/build/test'
```

In the child1 output, `'RIGIN'` is bad, the `$$` appears to have been evaluated a second time.

The [documentation has this note about exports](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html), which could be relevant, but doesn't really explain how to avoid it:

> In both of these forms, the arguments to `export` and `unexport` are expanded, and so could be variables or functions which expand to a (list of) variable names to be (un)exported.

Using `$$$$ORIGIN` in the top-level Makefile "works" for child1, but not for child2 which doesn't change the `LDFLAGS` value and ends up with `$$ORIGIN`.

This is GNU Make 3.81 under Linux.

The [RPATH post](https://enchildfone.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/a-description-of-rpath-origin-ld_library_path-and-portable-linux-binaries/) I linked to has a workaround, but feels like this shouldn't be necessary:

> `LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=XORIGIN/../lib" ./configure --prefix=/blabla/place`
>
> See the `X`? That will be replaced by a dollar sign later when you run `chrpath` on the resultant binaries.

Comment: what is the "special `$ORIGIN` value"? i found nothing about that in the makefile manual. also the `export` in child1.mk expanded the `$O` part of `$ORIGIN`. that is why you are left with `RIGIN`. do you need the `$ORIGIN` to be expanded in the child? or can it be expanded directly in the parent? that would probably make things easier.

Comment: `$ORIGIN` in the [RPATH](https://enchildfone.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/a-description-of-rpath-origin-ld_library_path-and-portable-linux-binaries/) tells the linux dynamic library loader to use a path relative to the binary when finding library dependencies.

The linker needs the literal string `$ORIGIN`, it's not being expanded with another value. I've tried to clarify the question.

Comment: if i understand correctly what you want to do is pass the literal string `$ORIGIN` to the linker. and you try to do so through multiple levels of makefile expansions and shell expansions all trying to grab that precious `$` away from your `$ORIGIN`.

Comment: @lesmana pretty-much!   Would have been nice if they chose @ instead of $ like MacOS did, but I can't do much about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On surface, this seems like a possible unintended bug with make integration with environment variables. It seems that whenever an environment variables is passed picked up by 'make', it will 'expand' any '$v', (and potentially other constructs).

Consider this very simple makefile

```
all:
    echo "V=$V"
    env | grep V=
```

Setting V to '$$SHELL' (bash export V='$$SHELL'), and running make will show that the internal 'V' variable is /bin/bash, while the environment variable is '$$SHELL'

```
echo "V=$SHELL"
V=/bin/bash
env | grep V=
V=$$SHELL
```

Putting a side the question if this is a feature or bug, you can use the $(value var) function to access the "raw" value. In the child make use:

```
# Append extra flags to env LDFLAGS, without 'expansion'
export LDFLAGS := $(value LDFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN/../..'
```

Comment: with `:=` it worked great! Otherwise I ended up with `LDFLAGS=$(value LDFLAGS) -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN/../..' -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/../..'` in the output

Comment: Thanks for checking, I've fixed the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example how to pass `$ORIGIN` through multiple levels of makefiles with `bash`:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

ifeq (${MAKELEVEL},0)
export LDFLAGS := -Wl,-rpath=`printf "%bORIGIN" "\044"`
endif

all :
    @echo MAKELEVEL=${MAKELEVEL} LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS}
    @if [[ ${MAKELEVEL} -lt 3 ]]; then ${MAKE}; fi
```

Outputs:

```
$ make --no-print-directory
MAKELEVEL=0 LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN
MAKELEVEL=1 LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN
MAKELEVEL=2 LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN
MAKELEVEL=3 LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN
```

---

Alternatively, if you are on Linux, build without `$ORIGIN` but then use [Exodus](https://github.com/intoli/exodus) for *painless relocation of Linux binaries – and all of their dependencies – without containers*.

Comment: Isn't this just resetting LDFLAGS at every level, rather than adding to it?

Comment: It is not, see `ifeq (${MAKELEVEL},0)`. Add a line `$(info setting LDFLAGS)` into that condition to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up additional variable of `O` to expand to the same before appending to `LDFLAGS`, so that even when `make` expands `$O` in `$ORIGIN`, it will still result in `$ORIGIN`:

```
$ cat child1.mk
# add an additional RPATH value
O := $$O
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath='$$ORIGIN/../..'

all:
        env | grep LDFLAGS
```

Output:

```
$ make
env | grep LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'
make -f child1.mk
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/raspy/so-62298900'
env | grep LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/../..'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/raspy/so-62298900'
make -f child2.mk
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/raspy/so-62298900'
env | grep LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/raspy/so-62298900'
```